# Middle button in Logitech t620 mouse

Tags: mouse, hardware, compatibility

I have bought a Logitech touch mouse t620. It works ok, but the middle button doesn't work..Any idea? is it working for you?

I'm on ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

I own the mouse and the middle click works for me. Try clicking with two and one fingers on the lower portion of the mouse (the middle works). Your mouse should be configured for one or the otehr.

If that doesn't work, use a Windows computer to configure the mouse (you'll need the logitech tool that is downloadable at logitech.com/downloads/t620)